# my token doesn't appeared on my BDD after a post fetch

Tags: node.js, react-native, token

i setup all my notification environnement with aws sns. Everything is working fine when i do the test.
Next step, i have to register the token on my bdd.

So i did my routes on my node js app like that :
router.post("/postFcmToken", connexionController.postFcmToken);

```
postFcmToken: (req, res) => {
    User.updateOne(
      { email: req.body.email },
      {
      $set: {fcmToken: req.body.fcmToken}
      },

      (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
          res.json({
            message: "une erreur s'est produite dans l'envoi du token",
          });
        } else {
          console.log(data)
          res.json({
            message: req.body.fcmToken,
          });
        }
      }
    );
  },
};
```

I catch my token on my index.js

```
PushNotification.configure({
    // (optional) Called when Token is generated (iOS and Android)
    onRegister: async function (token) {
      console.log("TOKEN:", token);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("tokenFcm", JSON.stringify(token))
    },
```

then i fetch my routes on my react native app :

```
const data = {
                fcmToken: await AsyncStorage.getItem("tokenFcm")
              };
          
              const headers = new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
              });
          
              const options = {
                method: 'POST',
                body:data ,
                headers: headers,
              };
          
              fetch('http://localhost:8080/connexion/postFcmToken', options)
                .then((response) => {
                  return response.json()
                }).then(
                  (responseObject) =>{
                    console.log("token", responseObject)
                  }
                )
          
            this.props.navigation.navigate('HomePage');
           }
```

i have no error and i have a code 200 on my back-end but the token doesn't register on my BDD. When i console.log the data on my back end i have that :

```
POST /connexion/postFcmToken 200 57.040 ms - 2
{
  n: 0,
  nModified: 0,
  opTime: {
    ts: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1620388505 },
    t: 11
  },
  electionId: 7fffffff000000000000000b,
  ok: 1,
  '$clusterTime': {
    clusterTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1620388505 },
    signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: [Long] }
  },
  operationTime: Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1620388505 }
}
```

Comment: where you are set AsyncStorage.setItem() ?

Comment: i edit it on my post , he is on my index.js

Comment: Because i catch it on my index.js ? Do you have an other idea ?